# Why do C/C++static libraries end in '.a'?

Tags: c++, c, static, posix, libraries

I am just doing a little work this morning making some static libraries. Why do static libraries end with '.a'?

No one in my office knew, so I thought I would ask around on Stack Overflow. We are writing code in C++, C, and Objective-C.

Comment: I suppose if anyone knows the history behind this that would be pretty interesting.

Comment: Tagged with POSIX -- on Windows the common extension is .lib.

Comment: @Billy: is the `.a` extension specified by POSIX though?

Comment: @Billy,jalf: it's more specific to GCC and likewise compilers... MinGW (Windows) also uses `.a` as the import/static library extension.

Comment: @Jalf: No, but it's a defacto standard on such machines.

Comment: as @rubenvb said, it's not really a property of POSIX, but rather of GCC and friends. The GCC tag would make more sense here, I feel

Comment: Other compilers use '.lib" extension.

Comment: Do you know the history of the .lib extension? Is it recent?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think the .a convention comes from using an "[archiver](http://www.oreillynet.com/linux/cmd/cmd.csp?path=a/ar)" to place the object files into a static library.

Answer (score 8):

That's just a convention on Unix-based systems. Visual Studio (Windows) generate `.lib` files.

In fact, I just discovered that there are several other namings, see Wikipedia article *[Library (computing), section File naming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_%28computing%29#File_naming)*.

Comment: I would be curious to know the history behind this convention. I wonder if it's documented anywhere?

Comment: I thought it might stand for something. Must have been a grad student that thought it was a good idea to give it a one letter extension lol

Comment: Yeah I added the link to wikipedia, that's interesting.

Answer (score 4):

It's an archive format (think of .zip or .tar) containing .o object files generated by "ar". The linker just treats it as if the object files were specified individually.

Comment: If you specified the .o file individually the linker might include them even if none of their symbols were specified, but with .a files linkers usually only bring in .o files within the archive who are required to satisfy the object being built.